# Google Sign In Auth2, how to persist the session?

Tags: javascript, session, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am trying to create a Google Sign In workflow, the problem i have, after the button click, the modal to select the account, i get the success callback and i can access the user basic profile.

The problem is, when i refresh the site. If i run `auth2.isSignedIn.get()` it always return false.

To be sure my code is not the problem, i copy this example from Google
`https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript/blob/master/index.html`

Enter the site with Google code, login, select my account from the modal and the site display my information but when i reload the site, the session disappear.

Maybe i am missing something, how we can persist the session so the user don't have to login every time we refresh the site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to implement the authentication in a server and maintain the session using `cookies`

You can use `node`, `passport` to achieve this. Hope this helps.